# CONCAT and CASE WHEN combined

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to create a query that concatenates the directions field that were involved in each transaction_id.

I've tried to do it creating a flag table with multiple case whens, and then querying on it, but as you can see in the image below, I'm having trouble to get a multiple 1's flag in one single row ID.

Any ideas on how to do it?

Here's the code and the tables I'm using:

```
SELECT
t2.trans_id,
CASE WHEN t2.dept_nbr IN (SELECT dept_nbr FROM t3 with WHERE dir = 'dir1') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS flag_dir1, 
CASE WHEN t2.dept_nbr IN (SELECT dept_nbr FROM t3 with WHERE dir = 'dir2') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS flag_dir2 
FROM  
t2
```

[Tables I'm using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWlXa.png)

Comment: Do **not** post images of tables. Paste their `CRATE` and `INSERT` statements.

Comment: @stickybit I do love a `CRATE` statement, does it come with free beer? :-)

Comment: @Charlieface: Oh yes it comes with free beer. But then only with `INERT` statements, so alcohol-free.

Comment: @stickybit Yes, `EXCEPT` in these trying times, when we must be very careful of `GERME` and `NOT JOIN` together in a `GROUP`. Remember we must also protect the `UNION` (uk)

Answer (score 1):

The solution you need is to group by the transaction id, then aggregate the distinct `dir`s. You need to join `t3` to get the `dir`

```sql
SELECT
    t2.trans_id,
    dir = STRING_AGG(t3.dir, ' - ')
FROM t2
JOIN t3 ON t3.dept_nbr = t2.dept_nbr
GROUP BY t2.trans_id;
```

I'm assuming that you have `STRING_AGG` available on your version of MSSQL, if not you must use a solution involving `FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE`, which I will leave as an exercise for yourself.